# How should year-only dates in ISO 8601 be interpreted?

Tags: data-modeling, iso8601

I'm looking at [yet another date specification](https://schema.org/Date) relying on the ISO 8601 standard. I understand that the latter accepts dates having the year only in their value eg, "2007". The question is: how are they interpreted? 1) only the year is given, nothing is said about day/month, either because they're unknown, or we want to refer to a year generically, as in: "next year for the dog in Chinese astrology", or 2) Jan/1 is implicit?

Did they define a standard interpretation for this, or is everyone free to do as they want (ie, spread incompatibility), or de-facto everyone does as they want?

As clarified in the comments, my main interest is in modelling schemas for data exchange and interoperability and hence it's important for me to know if/how these things are specified.

Comment: Personally I always understood it as the whole year with no date implied. I have combined with a month and day-of-month if I needed a date. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years) doesn’t tell, so I suppose you can do what you need to do for your situation.

Comment: @OleV.V. I wish it was so simple: I might interpret them as 'generic year, no day/month' specified, but then, a database might translate my data into 2019-01-01, I might receive data from 3rd parties having a different interpretation, etc. I work on data interoperability issues and that's why I wanted to understand if ISO says anything specific on this.

Comment: Thanks. You may want to add this background information to the question.

Comment: ISO-8601 allows you to encode unspecified information directly. Hence, there is a difference between the *year* "2007" and the (unspecified) *day* "2007-XX-XX". Whether your database preserves the distinction, rather than always picking a canonical day to represent the year, is another matter.